# Running salt-call locally on minion with master pillar data

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to run a sls file on salt-minion locally. I use the `salt-call --local state.sls <my_sls_filename>` command.

But the pillar data I try to fetch is available on the salt-master.

If I remove the `--local` then the salt looks for the state file on the master.

Any ideas how to get master pillar data while running `salt-call --local`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at the [Salt Masterless Quickstart](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/quickstart.html) documentation?

It seems to do what you're looking for, that is run a salt state locally without a master.

It says that in order to run masterless your pillar data also needs to be on the local minion.

> The --local flag tells the salt-minion to look for the state tree in
>   the local file system and not to contact a Salt Master for
>   instructions.

So I'm pretty sure what you're trying to do goes against the very purpose of using the `--local` flag

Comment: Yes. I am happy with the workaround I found for my problem. First I run salt-call without the --local tag and get my required pillar variables and store them as a pillar file.
salt-call --out=yaml pillar.get myconfig:master >> /srv/pillar/mpillar.sls

Then I run my local salt-call. Thank you for your answer.